# ffmpeg consume 252% of raspberrypi CPU

Tags: networking, image, cpu, ffmpeg, v4l2

I am using raspberry pi-4 8GB to take input from a video device `/dev/video0` and output it over a network `rtp://192.168.10.10:6001` I am using following ffmpeg command `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264 -f rtp "rtp://192.168.10.10:6001"` but the issue is it uses 252% of the cpu and raspberry pi get is getting on fire. How can I solve it

Comment: It's not using more CPU than you have, so don't worry, that's 252*"%"* of a possible 400*"%"* - the heat is probably because you don't have good cooling on the pi

Comment: Ok, I want to drop down the CPU consumption how can I?

Comment: @Mubahsir please do not add questions in comments ... edit your question instead

Comment: Check the actual temperature w/ `vcgencmd measure_temp`.  Throttling of the CPU to prevent overheat starts at 85° C, it will not destroy itself.

Comment: `I want to drop down the CPU consumption how can I?` use one or more of the following: 1 - lower resolution, 2 - lower quality, 3 - lower framerate,

Comment: Why do you want to reduce CPU usage - is there something that doesn't work?

Comment: Or you could use `h264_vaapi` or maybe `h264_v4lm2m2` encoder which I believe are hardware accelerated encoders?